# IndexOf method, &quot; vs. "

Tags: c#, indexof

I have a large string, and a part of this string starts like this:

```
data-json="{&quot;id&quot;:
```

and ends like this:

```
&quot;}}}"
```

I am using the IndexOf method to find positions of `data-json="` and the `"` in the end of the string.

However, when trying to find the index of the `"`, I get the index of the first `&quot;` instead (in the string in the top of the post).

How can I make the IndexOf method distinguish between `&quot;` and `"`?

This is how I search for the `"`:

```
string.IndexOf("\"", startIndex);
```

Of course maybe it *could* be possible to search for `}}}"` instead, but now I'm curious how to make the IndexOf method behave like I want it to.

Comment: Please give a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. String.IndexOf does *not* treat `"&quot;"` as `"`.

Comment: Why not just replacing it? `myData = myData.Replace("&quot;", "\"");`

Comment: By your assumption, you have one string you know start style and endstyle, so you can call str.Substring(....) to get related text what's the usage of indexof here?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, I'm sorry, I was unclear in my question. Updated.

Comment: @eightx2: You still haven't given a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Your question is still unclear, because the effect you're describing just doesn't exist.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, it doesn't exist, you're right about that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing, please forgive my rookie mistake:

The startIndex used in the IndexOf method was simply wrong (it found the `"` in `data-json="` because the startIndex value was too small).

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) method. That is intended for this purpose. If you want the last quote then this method is for you.

For instance:

```
// Determine where last quote is.
  int position = filepath.LastIndexOf('\"');
```

I am not sure if I understood your problem. So if this doesn't help or isn't related I apologize.